# OpenGL - texture not visible with blending enabled

Tags: c++, opengl

When I try to display texture on object it works but only with `GL_BLEND` disabled. When I enable blending:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The texture is just not visible anymore. Black screen.
I have really no idea whats going on. Its same for JPG and for PNG with alpha channel.

EDIT (more details):

Well, its hard to paste the code (objects, objects eveywhere and huge) but it goes something like this:

//initialization - i commented everything else

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

//preparing texture

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

int Mode = GL_BGR;

int nOfColors = image->format->BytesPerPixel;
if (nOfColors == 4) {
    if (image->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        Mode = GL_RGBA;
    else
        Mode = GL_BGRA;
} else if (nOfColors == 3) {
    if (image->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        Mode = GL_RGB;
    else
        Mode = GL_BGR;
}

// glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
//glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nOfColors, image->w, image->h, 0, Mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

//drawing

```
glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, _i );

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(x, y);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(x + width, y);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(x, y + height);
glEnd();

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL );
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

EDIT2

"black screen" may be little confusing - i meant that nothing is displayed (my background is black but it doesnt matter) - if i turn blending off i get nice texture on screen - with blending on nothing but background color

Comment: What happens if you do `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);` ? Do you have any GL_DST_ALPHA setting ?

Comment: This needs some more information. What else are you drawing. Is this textured object the only thing in the scene, or does **everything** disappear when you draw? What is the alpha of your texture?

Comment: Try to call `glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` before rendering the texture.

Comment: edited - added details.
now for testing i have only this one object (rect) with texture.

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE); gives me same black sceen
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE); gives me texture but its obviously useless :)
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); was there all the time - didnt work

Comment: Does `glGetError()` output something usefull while you are preparing the texture and binding it to be rendered?

Comment: Are you sure your internal format parameter is correct? It may be wrong since this parameter have a lot of possibilities and (for example) `GL_RGBA` is not 4, but 0x1908.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it finally started to work after i changed my image loading library to DevIL. Previous had problems with alpha channel it seems.

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to call glTexEnvf?

```
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

Here is example: http://unick-soft.ru/art/files/basicBlend.zip

For your case you need to look this code:

```
//draw texture
glPushMatrix();
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
texture.switchOffTexture();
Sphere.drawObject();  
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 7.0);
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE );
texture.bindTexture();
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);  
  glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
  glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
  glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

If you have problem with compilation, you can comment include: #include < gl\glaux.h >

Press 1, 2, 3 to select blending type. In case 3 you will see this result http://unick-soft.ru/art/img/blend/text_blend.png

Comment: This would be a better accepted answer IMHO since it actually provides a precise solution related to the code showed in the question.

Just to extend a little on it: the default GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE is GL_MODULATE, so changing it to GL_REPLACE is the most meaningful way to draw a full screen quad with the texture.

Setting the fg color to white would also work with GL_MODULATE but this could be considered a mere workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your alpha channel was all 0 - are you positive that you are reading your texture correctly (with alpha channel)? Try filling it by hand or check if it is really filled by whatever software you are using to read your files into pixels.